# Does GLaDOS actually say "There Really Was a Cake"?

Tags: portal

I found some youtube videos playing [this GLaDOS sound file](http://p1.portal2sounds.com/405) which I don't recall in the game at all. All the videos are fan made, none show the quote being made in game.

I've beaten the game about 4 times but I've never been able to discern this from her final words.

Was this included in the real game or is it an extra sound clip?

Comment: The line was there, but with all the explosions and with her getting further away its hard to discern. You can see it if you play with subtitles turned on as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

GameFAQs has a [script with all the lines from Portal](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/934386-portal/faqs/50477) "There really was a cake" is indeed in the script, GlaDOS says it when defeated.